# Disallow customer to change country in WooCommerce "My Account"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, readonly, country

I'm looking for a solution in which customers are unable to edit the country when changing their address.

We sell subscriptions, which are tied to specific countries. So changing an address is no problem, although we don't want to enable changes to a different country.

During checkout the check is done, but currently clients are able to change it from 'my account' once  the subscription is bought and active.

What I've tried so far is to disable the country dropdown fields with the following code:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'readdonly_country_select_field');

function readdonly_country_select_field( $fields ) {

    //Only on account pages
    if( ! is_account_page() ) return $fields;

    // Make country field read only
    $fields['country']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' );

    return $fields;
}
```

The problem is that the changed address is not saved. (No error messages are thrown, the pages just 'refreshes')

I assume this might be due to the fact that disabled fields don't get posted, but I cannot seem to find out how to do that. Does anyone now how to do that in this specific case?

Answer (score 1):

Besides using the `woocommerce_billing_fields` and the `woocommerce_shipping_fields` filter hooks you can use the `woocommerce_after_edit_address_form_{$load_address`} action hook so you can add the values ​​as hidden fields

So then you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    // Only on My account > Edit address section
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address') ) { 
        $fields['billing_country']['custom_attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
    }

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'filter_woocommerce_billing_fields', 10, 1 );

function filter_woocommerce_shipping_fields( $fields ) {
    // Only on My account > Edit address section
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address') ) { 
        $fields['shipping_country']['custom_attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
    }

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'filter_woocommerce_shipping_fields', 10, 1 );
    
function woocommerce_after_edit_address_form() {
    $billing_country = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();
    $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_country" value="<?php echo $billing_country; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_country" value="<?php echo $shipping_country; ?>">
    <?php   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_address_form_billing', 'woocommerce_after_edit_address_form' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_address_form_shipping', 'woocommerce_after_edit_address_form' );
```

---

**Update:** if you experience issues with the above answer you can also use the `woocommerce_default_address_fields` hook

```php
function filter_woocommerce_default_address_fields( $fields ) {
    // Only on account pages
    if ( ! is_account_page() ) return $fields;
    
    // Make country field read only
    $fields['country']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'filter_woocommerce_default_address_fields' );

function woocommerce_after_edit_address_form() {
    $billing_country = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();
    $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_country" value="<?php echo $billing_country; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_country" value="<?php echo $shipping_country; ?>">
    <?php   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_address_form_billing', 'woocommerce_after_edit_address_form' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_address_form_shipping', 'woocommerce_after_edit_address_form' );
```

Comment: Hi 7uc1f3r, your solution seems to empty the country/location field. It gives a "State / County is a required field." error message if the save button is hit and emptying the value for country/region.

Comment: @NickJWStone Nowhere is my answer fields are made empty, so no idea where that issue would arise, my answer has been tested in a default WooCommerce setup

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. I've also a more or less default setup, including the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin. Would any additional information be helpful?

Comment: @NickJWStone 
I can't take additional plugins into account in my answer, those kinds of questions are off-topic by the way, but you can always try the answer from my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have the same result with the updated code, which is quite similar to one of my own tries. I'll keep searching for a solution, might 'hide' the fields through .css as a temporary solution.